# Vue 3 - using plugin on test results in "resolveComponent can only be used in render() or setup()"

Tags: vue.js, jestjs, vuejs3

I'm trying to write a test for a component that relies on a custom component from a plugin. This is the current relevant code:

```
  describe('Render Test', () => {
    it('should render if modal is active', async () => {
      const customState = resetStoreConfig(emptyStore)
      customState.modules.modal.state.openModals = ['test-modal-name']
      store = new createStore(customState)
      wrapper = mount(ModalWrapper, {
        global: {
          plugins: [store, Purposeful],

        },
        props: {
          name: 'test-modal-name'
        },
      })
      expect(wrapper.vm.isActive).toBeTruthy()
      expect(wrapper.vm.isOpen).toBeTruthy()
      expect(wrapper.classes('modal-wrapper')).toBeTruthy()
    })
```

And this is the main.js on the Purposeful plugin:

```
import { library } from '@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core'
import { fal } from '@fortawesome/pro-light-svg-icons'
import { far } from '@fortawesome/pro-regular-svg-icons'
import { fas } from '@fortawesome/pro-solid-svg-icons'
import { FontAwesomeIcon, FontAwesomeLayers } from '@fortawesome/vue-fontawesome'
import { BootstrapVueNext } from 'bootstrap-vue-next'
import components from './components/bundle'
import layouts from './layouts/bundle'

library.add(fal)
library.add(far)
library.add(fas)

const Purposeful = {
  install (Vue = {}) {
    Vue.component('FontAwesomeIcon', FontAwesomeIcon)
    Vue.component('FontAwesomeLayers', FontAwesomeLayers)
    Vue.use(BootstrapVueNext)
    // components
    for (const componentName in components) {
      const component = components[componentName]
      Vue.component(component.name, component)
    }
    // layouts
    for (const layoutName in layouts) {
      const layout = layouts[layoutName]
      Vue.component(layout.name, layout)
    }
  }
}

export default Purposeful
```

However, I keep getting this error:

> console.warn
> [Vue warn]: resolveComponent can only be used in render() or setup().
>
> ```
>   38 |       store = new createStore(customState)
>   39 |
> > 40 |       wrapper = mount(ModalWrapper, {
>      |                      ^
>   41 |         global: {
>   42 |           plugins: [store, Purposeful],
>   43 |
> ```

If I use shallowMount, it works. If I remove Purposeful from the plugins list, it works as well, but I get

> Failed to resolve component: PModal

Since Purposeful is not being imported.

I've been googling, but couldn't find a hint on how to solve this issue. It seems that there are 2 vue instances, but I'm not sure how to debug that. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

I have tried removing `Vue` and using `app` on the Purposeful code instead, but still got the same error.